# Arm assembly str ldr

Tags: assembly, arm, qemu

i have this code

```
start:
ldr r0,=0x12345678
ldr r1,=0x00002000
str r0,[r1]
ldr r2,[r1]
stop: b stop
```

compile it to binary and store it in the qemu flash.
When i start qemy, i get this warning and the register r2 is 0:

```
QEMU 0.12.3 monitor - type 'help' for more information
(qemu) pflash_write: Unimplemented flash cmd sequence (offset 00002000, wcycle 0x0 cmd   0x0 value 0x12345678)
info registers 
R00=12345678 R01=00002000 R02=00000000 R03=00000000
R04=00000000 R05=00000000 R06=00000000 R07=00000000
R08=00000000 R09=00000000 R10=00000000 R11=00000000
R12=00000000 R13=00000000 R14=00000000 R15=00000010
PSR=400001d3 -Z-- A svc32
```

What is the problem?
Thank you

Comment: What is the code meant to do? What is the target machine? What does its memory map look like (in particular, what is mapped to address 0x2000)?

Comment: the code should only, store the value of r0 (12345678) into the ram address 2000. The target machine is a arm 7, how is emulated in qemu.

Comment: Are you positive that the machine you're emulating actually has some kind of RAM at address 0x2000? That's why I asked about the memory map.

Comment: Specifically, in your error message it say **pflash_write: Unimplemented flash cmd sequence**.  NOR/NAND flash is not like RAM.  Choose another address.  If your *QEMU* is *bare metal*, then it is most likely the case that the low memory emulates some flash boot code.